# Boundedness of an integral by its end point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

[image]

Could anyone please explain from the "but line" how the integral can be bounded by the end point $\beta$. I just need clarification on that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, this is using the claim that if $f$ reaches a maximum at $x=c$ and $g\geq 0$, then
$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x)\, dx \leq \int_a^b f(c)g(x)\,dx = f(c)\int_a^bg(x)\, dx$$
The inequality comes from the (easy to prove) fact that if $f\leq g$ then $\int_a^b f\leq \int_a^b g$. In your example, we have $f(x) = x^{-(k+2)}, g(x) = x^{2k+2}d\phi_i(x)$ ; $f$ is decreasing, and so its maximum occurs at the beginning of the interval, i.e. its maximum is $f(\beta)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really helpful. Please do you have a reference where I can read the proof of the claim. Thanks